# Are "The husband walked away from his wife" and "The husband walked out on his wife" roughly the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to oxford dictionary

> [walk away from somebody](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/walk-away?q=walk%20away): to leave a relationship, etc. instead of
> staying and trying to deal with it
>
> [walk out (on somebody)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/walk-out?q=walk%20out): ​(informal, disapproving) to suddenly
> leave somebody that you are having a relationship with and that you
> have a responsibility for

So, basically, according to the dictionary, these 2 structures are quite similar

Are "**The husband walked away from his wife**" and "**The husband walked out on his wife**" roughly the same?

Or **is there a difference between them?**

Comment: Walk away also has the meaning of moving away physically just as you can walk away from a train crash uninjured.

Comment: Whatever the dictionary says, I think _walk away from_ in this sense is more likely to be used of a situation than a person.

Comment: Or *The husband walked **off** from his wife*, which as with the ***away*** version would normally be ***literal***. You'd have to decide from context whether *The husband **left** his wife* referred to a temporary or permanent separation, but I reckon *as a complete sentence* it would usually be a permanent thing. As opposed to most likely temporary *The husband left his wife **at the station**.*

Comment: to **walk away is an idiom in English**: from a job, from a friendship, from a situation, even from a wife. To leave something behind. to walk out is more active and means to no longer want to be involved with someone.

Answer (score 3):

Colloquially, they have different meanings:

> "The husband walked away from his wife," could be used in [stage directions (blocking)](https://www.thoughtco.com/stage-directions-upstage-and-downstage-2713083), expressing a short-term action. It is less common to use that phrasing for a long-term relationship change.

> "The husband walked out on his wife," on the other hand, is almost exclusively used to mean he abandoned her.